# Custom template fields Drupal 7

Tags: 7, views, entities

In Drupal 6, I was able to use a Row Style Fields template and create variables to arrange and print later i.e.:

```
foreach ($fields as $id => $field) {
  if ($field->label == "Phone") {
    $f_phone = $field->content;
  }
}
print "<h2 class='content'>${f_phone}</h2>\n";
```

Then I was able to use the variable `$f_phone` in other places in the template.  This does not work in Drupal 7.  I am instead getting variable not found errors.

How would I do this in D7?

Comment: it depend what means 'other place' if you want print it out somewhere outside the row - it's impossible, because it's a template of a single row. You can do whatever you want with the field within the row, not outside.

Answer (score 1):

I figured I would reply to this question since I figured out an answer.  Don't know if this is the best way, but it works.

If you use the `views-view-fields.tpl` templates, you can skip the loop and directly list and style your fields ie:

```
print $fields['title']->content; 
print $fields['field_location']->content;
```

**the code above is inside your php tags